# How to call a onClick javascript function using bootstrap buttons and inside a form?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to change the css properties of a div when calling the onClick function.

```
<h1 id="hello">hello</h1>

<div id="notification" class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully posted to Facebook!
</div>

<div align="center" class="col-sm-4">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("distShare", null, new { area = "" }))
    {
        <button onclick="facebookButton2()" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Share this to Facebook</button>
    }
</div>
```

```
function facebookButton2() {
    document.getElementById("notification").style.visibility = visible;
    document.getElementById("notification").style.color = red;
    document.getElementById("hello").style.color = red;
}
```

The "hello" was simply for testing purposes.  I have tried using JQuery and the onSubmit function as well. The notification div starts off as visibility: hidden.

Comment: what is going on between the ```@``` symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the values you are passing should be strings, I honestly doubt that you have declared javascript variables called `visible` and `red` anywhere in your page:

```
function facebookButton2() {
    document.getElementById("notification").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("notification").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("hello").style.color = 'red';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was part of the problem XD

Answer (score 0):

Change your function as:

```
function facebookButton2() {
    document.getElementById("notification").setAttribute('style','visibility:visible');
    document.getElementById("notification").setAttribute('style','color:red');
    document.getElementById("hello").setAttribute('style','color:red');
}
```

See that working here: http://jsbin.com/rosubazuna/1/

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

The "distShare" was calling the distShare() method in my controller and that method returned me to a "new" view even though it was the same page.  I was essentially refreshing the page. So it was technically working and I just didn't realize it.  However, I also did have to change the values to strings as Darin Dimitrov suggested.  Thanks for your help!